# Usage of "homework," "schoolwork," and "assignment" in AmEng for schoolwork given to students to do at home

Tags: american-english, word-usage, formality, non-standard, dialects

As far as AmEng goes, is there any difference in using either ***homework***, ***schoolwork***, or ***assignment*** to call schoolwork given to students to be done at home? Can these be used just about interchangeably?

ASSIGNMENT vs. HOMEWORK

> 1. **assignment**
>
> > An assignment is a task that someone is given to do, usually as part of their job.
>
> *My first major assignment as a reporter was to cover a large-scale riot.*
>
> > An assignment is also a piece of academic work given to students.
>
> *The course has heavy reading assignments.*
>
> *When class begins, he gives us an assignment and we have seven minutes to work at it.*
>
> > **In American English, an assignment is also a piece of work given to students to do at home.** (emphasis is mine.)
>
> 2. **homework**
>
> > Work given to schoolchildren to do at home is also called *homework*.
>
> *He never did any homework.*

HOUSEWORK vs. HOMEWORK

> 1. **homework**
>
> > *Homework* is work that school pupils (*Chiefly BrEng*)/students (*Chiefly AmEng*) are given to do at home.
>
> *Have you done your English homework?*
>
> 2. **housework**
>
> > *Housework* is work such as cleaning or washing that is done in a house.
>
> *She relied on him to do most of the housework.*
>
> [Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homework)

SCHOOLWORK

> : work that is done in classes in a school or given to students to do at home.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schoolwork)

EDIT

Point to all of this is, if some native speakers of AmEng actually use exclusively "assignment" (or [***schoolwork***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=529&bih=347&tbm=bks&q=%22help+you+with+your+schoolwork%22&oq=%22help+you+with+your+schoolwork%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...41721.50716.0.51312.28.23.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..28.0.0.1X_WA4KM-2g)) for "homework" in the sense "schoolwork done at home," wouldn't the reason for that be that "homework" might have a quite different meaning in their vernacular, e.g. "housework" or "work done on the home"?

> ***Homeworker** in the US is a person who **works on homes** or a person who **works in homes** (maid). It is not a "clear" phrase at all because it tends to have ambiguous or no/multiple meanings. It is certainly something that I would expect to hear from a foreigner in the US.* (emphasis is mine.) [RyeBread - ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285480/is-there-a-word-phrase-to-describe-someone-who-works-from-home/285482#285482)

Please, consider the following example:

> *I'll help you with your **homework**/**schoolwork**/**assignments** once I'm done with the **housework**.* (standard AmEng)

-and-

> *I'll help you with your **schoolwork**/**assignments** once I'm done with the **homework**.* (nonstandard regional AmEng?)

Comment: You should find some better references, there's no need to confuse our poor answerers with the completely unrelated "housework".

Comment: @curiousdannii Actually, I thought that some people in the U.S. might use "homework" not for schoolwork to be done at home but for "housework."

Comment: Ah, I guess that's possible, but I really doubt it. Note that "home duties" is the same as housework.

Comment: @Elian I don't think I have heard anyone say homework for housework.

Comment: Yes they are interchangeable for work assigned to be done at home. No, no one ever uses homework for housework or vice versa. (unless we contrive a situation where someone is taking home ec and is assigned the task of doing laundry or something)

Comment: Where I went to school (Australia), an assignment is a much larger project than homework. Homework might be a few short answer questions at the back of a chapter, while an assignment might be to do a series of studies and to produce a 1000-word report.

Comment: @Jim Please see RyeBread's comments to Josh61's answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285480/is-there-a-word-phrase-to-describe-someone-who-works-from-home/285482#285482

Comment: @Elian - ok, so what’s the question?

Comment: All I ever recall, prior to college, was that "homework" was lengthened to "homework assignment" ("Your homework assignment is ...") when I was in high school, ca 1965.  And, of course, "homework" was never used in college, always "assignment".

Comment: I had an instructor once who always said "home lessons" and not "homework".

Comment: @HotLicks +1 for combining “homework assignment” and for noting how different levels of education/educators shorten it differently. (although the reason is probably that one might sound more “mature” than the other, I still wouldn’t put it past administrators at state institutions to warn their profs against using “homework” to keep their out-of-state students from using it to try to get in-state status/tuition).

Comment: @PapaPoule - That last bit makes no sense.  What does this have to do with in-state/out-of-state issues?

Comment: @HotLicks I should’ve bolded the “home” in “homework” to make my lame & OFF-TOPIC parenthetical about stingy administrators clearer: (I wouldn’t put it past administrators to warn profs against using [the word] "**home**work” [instead of “assignment”] to keep out-of-state students from using it [at status hearings] to get in-state status/tuition) Status-review officers trap students for replying “Back **home** with my parents” when asked where they’ll spend Christmas & they might not want to be trapped themselves with “But I do my **home**work right here at **home** in Chapel Hill, of course!”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've always used these terms in a different way that @James McLeod is describing them. Perhaps they are regional differences.

**Assignment**:  One singular task or project; large tasks may be broken up into smaller assignments. I may get one or more assignment per class. Whatever it is, it is thought of as a singular 'unit of work' when submitted or completed.
Complex, multi-part, or really large assignments are generally referred to as **projects**.

**Homework**: The collection of all the assignments I have to do at home

**Schoolwork**: The collection of all the assignments I have to do for school, regardless of the location of where it is done. Can be a synonym for *homework*, but less frequently used as such.

(Further clarification after reading some comments): An assignment can also be done IN school. *Assignment* just means 'one task'.  Which is why a lot of people do use *homework assignment*. They're specifying that this assignment is to be done at home (or at least, not during that class)

---

Not sure about other parts of the country, but I have never heard of *homework* used to describe not-related-to-school work done on or in the home.

Yes, **Housework** means work done for the house/home. This typically means tasks like cooking, cleaning, laundry, yard work, and small house repairs (when done on one's own home, this term is not used if professionals are called in).

I have never known a native speaker to confuse *housework* and *homework*, but if someone learning AmE were to mix the terms up, I do believe they would still be understood by most people.

Comment: I agree with this analysis. In my experience "in-class work" is the one clear-cut common term for "work done at school;" in contrast, "schoolwork" tends to mean simply "work done somewhere for school."

Answer (score 3):

The distinction I make is that an assignment is a larger project (an essay, a science fair project, a lab report), whereas homework includes assignments and day-to-day work like reading, doing a certain number of math problems, studying for a test, etc.

Comment: Interesting.  Although those math problems were assigned as well as the reading.  I make a distinction between doing homework and studying.

Comment: But when a parent asks a child "have you done your homework?" the intent is to find out if everything is done.

Comment: Agreed.  "Homework" is a short assignment intended to be completed quickly (generally that same day) and used to reinforce that day's lesson.  An "assignment" is a longer project that is completed over weeks or months, such as a science fair project, at-home experiment, a research paper, and so on.

Comment: A longer project was usually called a "project" (or, just as often, "long-term project") when I went to school.